# Knights and Knave variation question

Tags: logic, puzzle

This is the question:

> The island of Wantuutrewan is inhabited by two types of people:
>   knights who always tell the truth and knaves who always lie. Aaron
>   comes to a fork in a road on the island. One branch leads to the
>   ancient ruins he wants to visit, and the other branch leads deep into
>   the deadly jungle. At the fork stand two natives, one is a knight and
>   the other a knave, who know each other well. **However, Aaron has no
>   idea who is the knight and who is the knave.**
>
> Aaron wants to ask for
>   direction to the ruins, but he is allowed to ask only one question to
>   one of the two natives, and the natives, who understand English but
>   cannot speak it, **can only point with their fingers**. What single
>   question should Aaron ask so that he is sure to take the branch
>   leading to the ruins and not to the jungle?

I have tried googling but the ones I found on the Internet was such that

1)The individual knew who the knight and knave was

2)The knights and knaves could speak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this question works? I'm open for discussion on it, but here's what I came up with.

For this example, let's say the ruins are down the **right path** and the jungle is down the **left path.** Pick whichever native you like and ask them: *"Where will the person next to you claim the ruins are located?"*

If you addressed this question to the knight, he knows that the knave will point you in the wrong direction (down the left path towards the jungle) so the knight will point left to match what the knave would say.

If you addressed this question to the knave, he knows that the knight will point you in the right direction, so the knave will lie and instead also point left, down to the jungle.

Either way, take the path opposite the one that either native has pointed to.